# Populate first value based on group

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Could you please help me on below Dax logic

[image]

I am expecting my **First_Value**column needs to populate based on Date,datetime and subject column.

I have tried summarize and firstnoblank dax functions but doesn't useful for my requirement.

Thanks in advance,
PS

Comment: Do you want to create a calculated column or a measure with the result of `First_Value`?

Comment: I want to create Calculated Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this

**Table**

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
|     Date    | DateTime            | Subject | Value |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 05 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 01:00:00 | b       | 2500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 06 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 01:00:00 | A       | 6000  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 05 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 01:00:00 | A       | 4500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 06 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 01:00:00 | b       | 1500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 06 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 02:00:00 | A       | 4100  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 05 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 02:00:00 | A       | 4100  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 05 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 02:00:00 | b       | 3500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 06 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 02:00:00 | b       | 3500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 05 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 03:00:00 | A       | 5500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 05 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 03:00:00 | b       | 7500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 06 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 03:00:00 | A       | 5500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 06 May 2021 | 05/05/2021 03:00:00 | b       | 7500  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+-------+
```

You can create a calculated column as the following. The idea behind this is to create variables that can capture the values of the table and use them in filter contexts.

```
First_Value =
VAR SubjectValue = [Subject]
VAR DateVal = [Date]
VAR MinDateTime =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( [DateTime] ),
        FILTER ( 'Table', [Subject] = SubjectValue && [Date] = DateVal )
    )
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            [Subject] = SubjectValue
                && [Date] = DateVal
                && [DateTime] = MinDateTime
        ),
        [Value]
    )
```